# How to limit the result of binary conversion to a maximum of 8-bits (255)?

Tags: python, 8-bit

How can I limit the resuly to only 8 bits? I have to add two binary numbers and convert the result to decimal. How to limit the sum to only 8 bits or 255?

```
def BinaryToDecimal(binaryNum):
    binaryList = []
    decimalNumber = 0

    while binaryNum != 0:
            remainder = binaryNum%10
            binaryList.append(remainder)
            binaryNum = int(binaryNum/10)

    for i in range(len(binaryList)-1,-1,-1):
        decimalNumber = decimalNumber + binaryList[i] * (2**i)

    return decimalnumber
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the last 8 bits of your result, the simple solution is just to use [modular arithmetic](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/modulus.html) and use `% 256` to get the remainder after dividing by 256.

```
def BinaryToDecimal(binaryNum):
    binaryList = []
    decimalNumber = 0

    while binaryNum != 0:
        remainder = binaryNum % 10
        binaryList.append(remainder)
        binaryNum = int(binaryNum / 10)

    for i in range(len(binaryList) - 1, -1, -1):
        decimalNumber = decimalNumber + binaryList[i] * (2 ** i) 

    return decimalNumber % 256 # You also had a typo in this line
```

For example:

```
BinaryToDecimal(11111100000000)
Out[1]: 0
BinaryToDecimal(11111111111111)
Out[2]: 255
```

Alternatively, if you want to return 255 if the answer is > 255, the code would be:

```
return decimalNumber if decimalNumber < 256 else 255
```

This returns:

```
BinaryToDecimal(10000000)
Out[3]: 128
BinaryToDecimal(100000000)
Out[4]: 255
BinaryToDecimal(1000000000000)
Out[5]: 255
```

Incidentally: I fixed a typo in the `return` statement and your variable names don't conform to the [PEP-8](https://realpython.com/python-pep8/#naming-styles) Python styles - variables should be in lower case separated by underscores like `binary_num` and `decimal_number`

Answer (score 0):

I have written a function for you:

```py
def bin_to_dec(bits,fmt = None):
    if bits != 0:
        bits = str(bits)
        if fmt == 'big':
            bits = bits[:8]
        else:
            bits = bits[-8:]
        try:
            return int(bits,2)
        except ValueError:
            print("Enter bits only no number other than 1 and 0!!!")
    return 0
```

and on doing this:

```py
>>> print(bin_to_dec(11111111110000,'big'))
255
>>> print(bin_to_dec(11111111110000,'little'))
240
```

Just pass your binary as `int`, if you have it as string than you can remove `bits = str(bits)` line from my code.
`fmt` is for data format for little or big endian depends on you.
To understand Little and Big Endian [Check Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/big-endian-and-little-endian).
Default is little and on any error it will always return 0.

Example if you gave anything other than 1 or 0 in bits:

```py
>>> print(bin_to_dec(11111112110000,'little'))
Enter bits only no number other than 1 and 0!!!
0
```

You will get 0 and a bonus print output